# rails 3 can can ability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, cancan

I am using can can gem to restriction user based on role
there is no model for product

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    authorize_resource :class => false

   def index
     @customers=Customer.all
   end
end
```

in ability.rb

when i write like this can can allow me to acess the product controller

```
can [:index], :product
```

but when i write like  this

```
can [:index], :products
```

it doesnot allow me to acess the product controller

my doubt is the controller name is **products** but in ability why we need to write **product**
and it's possibility to write plural in ability.rb ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is documented at Cancan [Non RESTful controllers](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Non-RESTful-Controllers) (aka when you have a controller without corresponding model) and the docs example shows:

```
class ToolsController < ApplicationController
  authorize_resource :class => false
  def show
    # automatically calls authorize!(:show, :tool) # Note the singular :tool
  end
end
```

So, like you already figured, you need to pass singular resource symbol in `Ability.rb`

```
can :index, :product
```

You could read more on this [Github Ticket](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/22)